# Fastest way to pick all unique pairs out of a range of numbers; if you could pick more than 2 at a time

Tags: graph-theory, combinations

Question:
I have list of numbers, $\{1,2...1000\}$. This has ${1000 \choose 2}=499500$ unique pairs.
If I pick 2 numbers at a time from the list, I can pick all unique pairs in 499500 tries.
If I pick 8 numbers at a time from the list, what is the lowest number of tries in which I can pick all the unique pairs?
Repeating of pairs is allowed.

example: with smaller numbers : 8 (instead of 1000 numbers), 4 (instead of 8 picks)

list - 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8; unique pairs - 28 (8c2).

If I pick 2 numbers at a time from the list, it will take me 28 tries to pick all the unique pairs.

If I pick 4 numbers at a time, it will only take 6 tries to pick all the unique pairs

try 1 - 1,2,3,4 - covers these pairs, 1,2; 1,3; 1,4; 2,3; 2,4; 3,4

try 2 - 5,6,7,8 - covers these pairs, 5,6; 5,7; 5,8; 6,7; 6,8; 7,8

try 3 - 1,2,5,6 - covers these pairs, 1,5; 1,6; 2,5; 2,6; (1,2; 5,6; - repeating)

try 4 - 3,4,7,8 - covers these pairs, 3,7; 3,8; 4,7; 4,8; (3,4; 7,8; - repeating)

try 5 - 1,2,7,8 - covers these pairs, 1,7; 1,8; 2,7; 2,8; (1,2; 7,8; - repeating)

try 6 - 5,6,3,4 - covers these pairs, 5,3; 5,4; 6,3; 6,4; (5,6; 3,4;  - repeating)

Comment: When you say "I can pick all unique pairs in 499500 tries.", are you saying "There is a very lucky way to pick all unique pairs in 499500 tries when there are no repetitions in the picks." or are you saying "Since repetitions are disallowed, after 499500 picks, all pairs have been picked."  My interpretation is the latter, but this is incompatible with "Repeating of pairs is allowed."  Also, if repeating is allowed, a sequence of picks that only ever pick the same pair never completes...

Comment: Also, are you familiar with [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)?

Comment: @EricTowers Repeating pairs is allowed, but why would you pick the same pair twice if you're trying to pick all the unique pairs? (Are you assuming that "pick" means "pick randomly"? That's not what's happening.) It's different in the picking 8 numbers at a time version: then, you might (maybe) want to repeat a pair because of overlap between the sets of 8.

Comment: @MishaLavrov : Is it unclear that I am asking what meaning is to be attached to OP's "Repeating of pairs is allowed."?  You seem to have decided what it means, but you are not the OP.

Comment: @EricTowers The example seems to make things clear.

Comment: @EricTowers - I can pick all unique pairs in 499500 tries -> means the slowest way of picking things, (1,2), (1,3), (1,4)..... etc. This way i will pick all pairs in 499500. If i pick (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) in one shot i picked 28 pairs. so what is the most "clever" way of picking sets of 8, with a goal of 'completing all pairs as fast as possible' in mind. "repeating is allowed" -> means if you keep picking sets of 8, you will repeat some pairs eventually.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minimum number of subsets of $A$ of a given order that contain all possible pairs of elements of $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1734855/minimum-number-of-subsets-of-a-of-a-given-order-that-contain-all-possible-pair)

Answer (score 0):

Divide into 8 piles of size 127, including a little repetition.  Rename them as ordered pairs from $(1,1)$ to $(8,127)$.

With $127^2$ octets, namely $O_{ab}=\{(i,ai+b\mod127)\}$ you can connect any numbers from different piles.  You then need to connect numbers within a pile.

Divide each $127$ pile into eight piles of $17$, with some repetition, and you need $17^2$ octets for each $127$ pile.

You now have $64$ piles of $17$, and all numbers in different piles have been done.

Within a pile of $17$, each number must be in three octets, which is $51$ places needed, or at least seven octets.  I think that is possible, but I've only covered $17$ by using eight octets.

That gives a total of $127^2+8×17^2+64×8=18953$ octets.   The obvious minimum of ${1000\choose2}/{8\choose2}$ is $17840$